# RxJs expand method causing extra HTTP call

Tags: javascript, angular, http, rxjs

I use the following approach to send multiple HTTP calls:

```
listEmployees() {
  of({
    hasNext: true,
    pageIndex: 0,
    items: []
  }).pipe(
    expand(data => this.employeeService.list(data.pageIndex+1, 100) //100 records for each call
    .pipe(
      map(newData => ({...newData, pageIndex: data.pageIndex+1}))
    )),
    takeWhile(data => (data.hasNext|| data.pageIndex === 1)),
    map(data => data.items),
    reduce((acc, items) => ([...acc, ...items]))
  )
  .subscribe(result => {
    this.employees = result;
  });    
}
```

However, as the call is made at the first step, `takeWhile` is only executed after the next HTTP call is already made. But I need to check the `hasNext` variable of the HTTP response and then decide to send the next HTTP call. For this, I tried to make something like that, but it does not work as teh pageIndex is not changed or some reason etc.

```
listEmployees() {
  this.employeeService.list(data.pageIndex+1, 100).pipe(  //100 records for each call
    expand((data) => {
        if(data.hasNext) {
          return this.employeeService.list(data.pageIndex+1, 100);                
        } else {
          return of(EMPTY);
        }
    })
    .subscribe(result => {
        this.employees = result;
    });    
}
```

How can I fix the problem? I think I should use the second approach by modifying the first one so that it send subsequent calls after checking the condition. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set the inclusive flag on your takeWile

```js
listEmployees() {
  of({
    hasNext: true,
    pageIndex: 0,
    items: []
  }).pipe(
    expand(data => 
      this.employeeService.list(data.pageIndex+1, 100).pipe(
        map(newData => ({...newData, pageIndex: data.pageIndex+1}))
      )
    ),
    takeWhile(data => data.hasNext, true), // Inclusive = true
    map(data => data.items),
    reduce((acc, items) => ([...acc, ...items]))
  )
  .subscribe(result => {
    this.employees = result;
  });    
}
```